# Get Data Attribute Value Without CamelCasing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to pull out a data attribute value *without* grabbing the data attribute via camel case?

Example: Take this button:

```
<button id="my-button" type="button" data-some-url=<%=some_dynamic_path%>>Lookup</button>
```

When this button is clicked I want to do some ajax stuff.  Currently I only know how to grab the data attribute *value* by camel casing:

```
$("#my-button").on("click", function(){
  url = $(this).data("someUrl");
});
```

Instead I would prefer to grab the data attribute value like so, but of course it doesn't work:

```
url = $(this).data("some-url");
```

**Question:** Is there some way I can grab the data attribute value by keeping the hyphens in there?

---

**Update**:

I made a simple typo.  The second version does in fact work:

```
url = $(this).data("some-url");
```

That will successfully get you the data attribute value.

Comment: Well, technically neither of those would work, since they're not quoted, but just use `$(this).attr('data-some-url')` if you can't stand the camel...

Comment: What makes you think the second version doesn't work?

Comment: ahh! I just made a typo.  The second version does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the name as a string to the data method.

```
$('#my-button').data('some-url')
```

Comment: that doesn't change the fact that this is how you get the data attribute using the data method.

Comment: But it's not an answer to the question, since the question says this is what he tried.

Comment: If he tried it and did not get the correct attribute, there is something else wrong, this answer is correct to the question above, And at the time of asking the question that was the problem. `$('#el').data(some-url)` is invalid, wrapping it in a string is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could ignore it's data-semantics and treat it like any other attribute:

```
url = $(this).attr( 'data-some-url' );
```

Comment: If you do that, you won't benefit from jQuery's `data()` handling. jQuery does not push changes in `data()` back to the DOM to save resources.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 For data added by a framework as in the question, that's usually not a concern.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 That's part of what I meant by "ignoring the data-semantic". The fact that jQuery'S `data()` doesn't push back to the DOM element, sometimes is a disadvantage, e.g., for conditional formatting using CSS.